# I'm getting a fs.js:347 throw new TypeError('Bad arguments');

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, web, web-development-server

I was trying to follow a tutorial on creating a router with Node.js. Here is the code for the router..

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response){
    console.log('Connection');
    var path = url.parse(request.url).pathname;

    switch(path){
        case '/':
            response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            response.write('hello world');
            break;
        case '/socket.html':
            fs.readFileSync(__dirname + path, function(error, data){
                if (error){
                    response.writeHead(404);
                    response.write("opps this doesn't exist - 404");
                }
                else{
                    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
                    response.write(data, "utf8");
                }
            });
            break;
        default:
            response.writeHead(404);
            response.write("opps this doesn't exist - 404");
            break;
    }
    response.end();
});

server.listen(8001);
```

When i visit http:/localhost:8001/socket.html, i get a blank screen in my browser, and my terminal says

```
Connection
fs.js:347
throw new TypeError('Bad arguments');
      ^
TypeError: Bad arguments
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:347:11)
    at Server.<anonymous> (/Users/Vik/Desktop/NodeJS/routingToDifferentUrls.js:15:20)
at Server.emit (events.js:110:17)
at HTTPParser.parserOnIncoming [as onIncoming] (_http_server.js:491:12)
at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:111:23)
at Socket.socketOnData (_http_server.js:343:22)
at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:163:16)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:126:10)
at TCP.onread (net.js:529:20)
```

then exits.

Can anyone please explain why I am getting this error???
And yes, I have created my socket.html file, which displays nothing but simple text saying "this is our socket.html file."

Thanks a ton in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it looks like you are using `fs.readFile` which is asynchronous. so `response.end()` is being called before that finishes.hence your error message `write after end`.You really want to be using [fs.readFileSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_filename_options) to grab the contents of socket.html. like `var data = fs.readFileSync.(__dirname + path)`

Comment: Thanks man! That got rid of the error. But now, I have a different error. Do you mind helping me out on this one too..

fs.js:347
    throw new TypeError('Bad arguments');
          ^
TypeError: Bad arguments
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:347:11)
    at Server.<anonymous> (/Users/Vik/Desktop/NodeJS/routingToDifferentUrls.js:15:20)

Comment: I edited the original question with the new issue (only thing i did was change fs.readFile to fs.readFileSince)

Comment: Yeah, it is kicking back `Bad arguments` because you are passing a callback as a parameter to a readFileSync, which does not accept a callback as a second parameter, but an options hash. Try `var data = fs.readFileSync((__dirname + path));response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});response.write(data);`..directly after the case statement.

Comment: yaaayy finally!
Thank you so much man! I literally spent 3 hours trying to figure this out. I really appreciate your help!